# LinQ sum group by between using Lambda

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

Help me convert it to lambda

```
select 
    Orders.Order_Date as date, sum(Amount) as amount
from 
    Orders 
inner join 
    OrderDetails on Orders.Order_ID = OrderDetails.Order_ID
where 
    Order_Date<= '2017-02-10' and Order_Date<= '2017-02-11'
group by 
    (Order_Date)
order by 
    date asc
```

**My model:**

```
public class TotalIncome
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime fromDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime toDate { get; set; }
    public List<IncomeByDate> ListIncome { get; set; }
}
```

**my controller:**

```
var ba = db.Orders.Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
.Where(o => o.Order_Date >= startDate)
.Where(o => o.Order_Date <= endDate);
```

i can't sum amount and group by. Help me fix it

Comment: You're using both EF4 and EF6 in your project?

Comment: @Will i using EF 6

Comment: @GertArnold sr,next time i will show more infomation

Comment: @GertArnold help me fix it

Comment: Your model is not related to the query. I *assume* `Amount` is in `OrderDetails`, but who can tell?

Comment: @GertArnold if i called, i will set to model

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Amount is a member of OrderDetails

```
var ba = db.Orders
  .Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
  .Where(o => o.Order_Date >= startDate)
  .Where(o => o.Order_Date <= endDate)
  .GroupBy(o => o.Order_Date)
  .Select(s => new {
    date = s.Key,
    amount = s.Sum(o => o.OrderDetails.Sum(od => od.Amount)),
  });
```